# url contain double dots between page name and extention

Tags: c#

I am sending email through code which contains Page URL.
the code returns proper URL text and href value. but in the email I am getting double dots between login and aspx like (login..aspx),but as you can see it is hardcoded in the text. the issue is I am getting (login..aspx). PageName doesnot contain . in it. 
any help

code to generate url :

```
RedUrl = "<a href='" + domain + "/login.aspx?redurl=" + PageName + ".aspx&id=" + 
         id.EncodeString()'>" + domain + "/login.aspx?redurl=" + PageName + 
         ".aspx&id=" + id.EncodeString() "</a>";
```

Comment: Is it a joke? simply remove the dot in your code

Comment: `PageName` probably contains a `.` at the end. You should also be looking at using `string.Format` to make your code easier to read.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code using Visual Studio to see what value `PageName` has?

Comment: the problem is not with PageName variable The Problem is on this part of the String i.e.("/login.aspx?redurl=") This part of the string get converted into ("/login..aspx?redurl=") this error is very inconsistent

Comment: Please show how you get your pagename variable.

Comment: I am using simple variable to store page name and passing it in the URL. e.g  string pagename="NewPage"; the page name is comming proper and url I get at the time of debugging is correct. but, how does it get converted into login..aspx in the email that i am not able to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `PageName` ends with a dot, try trimming it: `PageName.TrimEnd(".".ToCharArray())`